# Getting access to config data from routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, config

I my rails app in `routes.rb`  I need to have access to some config values from an `yml` config stored in the same folder. As far as I know, `routes.rb` gets loaded or might get loaded priour  to a time  when `routes.rb` get loaded.

How can I read some config data and use it in `routes.rb` if `routes.rb` gets loaded first and then `config.yml` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails startup process follows the following pattern:

```
1. railties/exe/rails
2. railties/lib/rails/app_loader.rb
3. bin/rails
4. config/boot.rb
5. rails/commands.rb
6. rails/command.rb
7. actionpack/lib/action_dispatch.rb
8. rails/commands/server/server_command.rb
9. Rack: lib/rack/server.rb
10. config/application
11. Rails::Server#start
12. config/environment.rb
13. config/application.rb
```

You can pick any of these files to do your pre-router loading process.

If I recall correctly, the `routes.rb` file isn't loaded in the startup, but in runtime.